# Table has no column named xyz while inserting data into SQLite database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

It says that the column name bmi does not exist. The resulting Error message is that the system cannot find a column called bmi. I checked it already a couple of times and I couldn't find a mistake in the code. Maybe you guys see one... The full Stack Dump is attached after the code.

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bmiwerte.db";

public static final String TABLE_BMIS = "bmis";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_BMI = "bmi";


public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_BMIS = "CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLE_BMIS
        +" ("
        +COLUMN_ID
        +" INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +COLUMN_NAME
        +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY"
        +COLUMN_BMI
        +" TEXT"
        +");";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //Lässt Query in SQL laufen
    Log.i("exxxx", "Creating Check");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_BMIS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_BMIS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addValues(BMI_Werte wert){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, wert.get_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_BMI, wert.get_bmiWert().toString());
    Log.i("exxx", wert.get_name());
    Log.i("exxxx", wert.get_bmiWert().toString());

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_BMIS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteValues(String name){
    Log.i("exxxx", "deleteValuse");
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_BMIS + " WHERE " +
            COLUMN_NAME + "=\"" + name + "\";");
}

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_BMIS;
    String test = "DESCRIBE " + TABLE_BMIS;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

Error and Stack Dump:

---

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its typo**, you forget `,` while creating table

```
+COLUMN_NAME
+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " // add , after primary key
+COLUMN_BMI
```

Uninstall application from emulator/device and install it again will resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

`+COLUMN_NAME
        +" TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"`
add "," after "TEXT PRIMARY KEY".